# Manually configure routing tables for azure virtual network (point-to-site)

Tags: powershell, azure, vpn, azure-virtual-network

I am having trouble connecting to my virtual network using the azure VPN client on windows 10 (I get an error about the certificate not found).I found a way to manually configure the VPN, I can successfully connect to it, ping my virtual machines from my local machine, ping my local machine from my virtual machines, remote desktop to it with the virtual network IP address (or hostname) and even connect to my shared folders on my local machine from the Virtual machines. What I can't do, and want to do is to connect to my shared drives on the VMs from my local machine (it works perfectly when I connect with the azure vpn client from windows 7). I've noticed when you connect through the vpn client it actually sets up the routing tables for you. So my question is: **How do you configure it manually with powershell?**

PS: For some reason you can't go to the IPV4/6 or any properties on your VPN connection on windows 10, So i have to do everything through powershell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't the routing tables. The problem was that there was credentials stored in my my Credential Manager (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager) for the VM which was incorrect, I think, I cleared it, and all worked. And by the way, I got the Azure VPN client to work on my windows 10 machine with help from [this article](http://terrytlslau.tls1.cc/2015/03/setup-point-to-site-vpn-to-microsoft.html)